# acumatica project webservice endpoint changes lost

Tags: project, acumatica, endpoint

Acumatica is not updating the project with Endpoint changes, even if RELOAD FROM DATABASE is done on the Project->WebServicesEndpoints page.

Since Endpoint changes are not updated in the project, if the project is published, then all work on the Endpoint is lost.

Verified by exporting project, and also viewing project XML.

If a new project is created, the Endpoint is added, then this new project has the updated Endpoint.

Steps to re-create:

1. Create Endpoint - Add a few entries
2. Create Project
3. Add Endpoint to Project
4. Add new ENTRY into Endpoint
5. In Project->WebServiceEndpoints, click RELOAD FROM DATABASE

View Project XML via Project->File->EditProjectXML (easier than exporting)

Verify that the new ENTRY to the Endpoint is not in the XML

Comment: Seems like this issue was fixed a while ago. What build of Acumatica are you using?

Comment: @samol518 thanks, the About says 2018 R1 build 18.108.0016 - This is a custom copy (software purchased, then modified) so I don't know if the build version is our internal build, or the build that was purchased and then modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue that has been fixed in the following builds

- 2017R2: 17.211.0022
- 2018R1: 18.109.0031
- 2018R2: 18.200.0075

You are using the build in 2018R1 that is just before the one that has the fix.
If this is really bothering you consider upgrading your Acumatica version, if not please make sure to delete the endpoint entry in the customization project and re-add it to the project. That will update it properly in the project.

Comment: Is this unique to Endpoints, or are there other parts of the Project that have a similar issue?